# Retrieving data from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to retrieve data from this array in php.

```
array(2) {
   ["getWysiwyg"]=>
     string(37) "[{"basicsDescription":"<p><br></p>"}]"
   ["getGoal"]=>
     string(27) "[{"iconURL":"","title":""}]"
}
```

I tried `Input::get('getWysiwyg')` it returns `[{"basicsDescription":"<p><br></p>"}]`

Now how could i get the value i.e `<p><br></p>`

Comment: That's JSON which you need to decode with `json_decode()`

Comment: aaand here is the link to [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) ;)

Answer (score 1):

As I see your array items are json encoded ..

Try to decode them as this:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $decodedValue = json_decode($value, true);
    print_r($decodedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), because the string `[{"basicsDescription":"<p><br></p>"}]`represents an array with an object in [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

```
$string = '[{"basicsDescription":"<p><br></p>"}]';

$objectArray = json_decode( $string );
```

**$objectArray now looks like:**

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
      ["basicsDescription"]=>
      string(11) "<p><br></p>"
    }
}
```

To get the value of **basicsDescription** you need to access the array in this case with the index 0, then you have the object:

```
$object = $objectArray[0];
```

Once you've got the object you can access it's attributes with the object operator `->`:

```
$object->basicsDescription;// content: <p><br></p>
```

Short form of this:

```
$string = '[{"basicsDescription":"<p><br></p>"}]';// in your case Input::get('getWysiwyg')

$objectArray = json_decode( $string );
$objectArray[0]->basicsDescription;
```

If it's possible, that there are more than one item in it, you should go for [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

**If all items of your array representing JSON strings you can use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)**:

```
$array = array(
    "getWysiwyg" => '[{"basicsDescription":"<p><br></p>"}]',
    "getGoal" => '[{"iconURL":"","title":""}]'
);

$array = array_map( 'json_decode' , $array );

echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $array );
```

This will output:

```
array(2) {
  ["getWysiwyg"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
      ["basicsDescription"]=>
      string(11) "<p><br></p>"
    }
  }
  ["getGoal"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
      ["iconURL"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["title"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decode and print as follows

```
$object = json_decode(Input::get('getWysiwyg'));
print $object[0]->basicsDescription;
```

or directly with the help of array dereferencing

```
print json_decode(Input::get('getWysiwyg'))[0]->basicsDescription;
```

will output

```
<p><br></p>
```